# Call method of interface implements with child fragment From container activity Android

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

I'm stuck with communication between activity and fragment using interface. I have created activity with child fragment. I wanna do some stuff with continuous thread defined in activity and during that thread when I'm getting some result at that time I wanna trigger to child fragment to do something.

My Container Activity

```
public class MySpaceActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity {

private OnSetLastSeenListener mListner;

public static Thread mThread = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setHeaders(Const.MY_SPACE);
    super.setSubmenus(Const.MY_SPACE,
            Utils.getSubmenuList(Const.MY_SPACE, MySpaceActivity.this),
            submenuBean);
    // super.attachFragment(submenuBean);
}

@Override
public void setHeaderSubMenu(SubmenuBean subMenuBean) {
    // txt_submenu.setText(subMenuBean.getSubmenu_name());
    this.submenuBean = subMenuBean;
    Log.print("::::: setHeaderSubMenu ::::");
    super.attachFragment(submenuBean);
}

public void setsubFragment(SubmenuBean subMenuBean) {
    this.submenuBean = subMenuBean;
    super.attachSubFragment(submenuBean);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    popLastFragment();
}


private void popLastFragment() {
    if (super.getNumberOfChilds() > 1) {
        super.popSubFragment();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected Fragment getFragement() {

        StudentsFragment fragment = new StudentsFragment(Const.MY_SPACE,
                getSubmenubean());
        return fragment;

}

public SubmenuBean getSubmenubean() {
    return submenuBean;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mThread = new Thread(new CountDownTimer(MySpaceActivity.this));
    mThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();

    if (mThread.isAlive()) {

        mThread.interrupt();
        mThread = null;
    }

}

public void updateLastSeen(){

        Log.print("::::::Call Interface::::::");
        mListner.updateLastSeen();
     }

class CountDownTimer implements Runnable {

    private Context mContext;
    private JSONObject mJsonObject;
    private JSONArray mJsonArray;

    public CountDownTimer(Context mContext) {

        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    // @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {

                HttpChatLastSeen mChat = new HttpChatLastSeen();
                mJsonObject = mChat.Http_ChatLastSeen(mContext);

                String mResult = mJsonObject.getString("Result");

                if (mResult.equalsIgnoreCase(String
                        .valueOf(Const.RESULT_OK))) {

                    mJsonArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("UserData");

                    for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        new DbStudentMasterBll(mContext).update(
                                "last_seen", mJsonObject
                                        .getString("LastSeen"), Integer
                                        .parseInt(mJsonObject
                                                .getString("UserId")));
                    }

                } else {

                    Log.print("MY LAST SEEN Response : "
                            + mJsonObject.toString());
                }

                updateLastSeen();

                Thread.sleep(15000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.print("ChatLastSeenThread : ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

   }

  }
```

My Child Fragment With Interface :

```
public class StudentsFragment extends Fragment implements OnSetLastSeenListener{

TextView txt_submenu;
ListView list_students;
SubmenuBean submenuBean;
int Mainmenu;
MySpaceActivity mMySpaceActivity;
ArrayList<DbStudentMasterBean> studentsList;
StudentsAdapter mAdapter = null;
OnSetLastSeenListener mListner;

public StudentsFragment() {
    super();
}

public StudentsFragment(int Mainmenu, SubmenuBean submenuBean) {
    this.submenuBean = submenuBean;
    this.Mainmenu = Mainmenu;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_students, container,
            false);
    mMySpaceActivity = (MySpaceActivity) getActivity();

    txt_submenu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_submenu);
    txt_submenu.setText(submenuBean.getSubmenu_name());
    txt_submenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMySpaceActivity.openDrawer();
        }
    });
    list_students = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_colleagues);


    studentsList = new DbStudentMasterBll(getActivity()).getAllRecords();

    mAdapter = new StudentsAdapter(getActivity(), studentsList, handler);
    list_students.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    list_students.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            DbStudentMasterBean bean = (DbStudentMasterBean) parent
                    .getAdapter().getItem(position);

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = CHAT;
            msg.obj = bean;

            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

        case CHAT:
            submenuBean.setTag(VIEWCHATSTUDENT);
            DbStudentMasterBean bean = (DbStudentMasterBean) msg.obj;
            mMySpaceActivity.setsubFragment(submenuBean);

            break;
        }
    };

};

@Override
public void updateLastSeen() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.print("!!!!!!!!!Refresh Adapter!!!!!!!!!!!");
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

My Interface :

```
  public interface OnSetLastSeenListener {

    public void updateLastSeen();

  }
```

So I have implemented interface **OnSetLastSeenListener** with my child fragment **StudentsFragment** . Now I'm calling method of tht interface **updateLastSeen()** from my container activity with thread. But it is not getting trigger to child fragment where I have implemented interface. So I don't know whether it is good way to communicate or not? Let me take your help to suggest on this solution or best way to communicate from child fragment to parent activity.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `interface` when you want to communicate something from `Fragment` **to** `Activity` and not vice versa.

In your case, you can directly call the method in `Fragment` from `Activity` through `fragment object`. No need to use interface.

Something like this (For static fragments)

```
 StudentsFragment fragment = (StudentsFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentid);
 if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
       fragment.updateLastSeen();
  }
```

For dynamic fragment you can use the fragment object directly.

Comment: When I do as you said, It is calling that method multiple times even it should be call only one time. Don't know why?

Comment: It is not static fragment. It's dynamic fragment!!

Comment: For dynamic fragment you can use the fragment object directly. I think you are calling `updateLastSeen();` inside `while` loop.put it outside `while loop`

Comment: I need to call it multiple times. But it should be wait till 15 seconds as I have put Thread.sleep(15000). But it is calling continuously without sleep mode.

Comment: Actually my thread is continuously calling without sleep when that fragment is loaded.

Comment: Actually it is better to use `Timer` rather than using while loop with the sleep. You want to call `updateLastSeen` method continuously with the gap of 15 sec?? When you gonna stop calling method??

Comment: Yup brother, I have just got blinking in my mind to use Timer just before a second. I think that will be better idea. Let me try. N it will destroy when my activity will be destroy.

Comment: Ok..yup..it is better to use Timer